# Terraform apply making changes to imported resource in state when resource has not changed

Tags: azure, terraform, resources, state, databricks

I have the following config:

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.25.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.4.0"
    }
  }

}


provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "uat-sub"
  features {}  
  subscription_id = "sfsdf"
}

provider "databricks" {
  host  = "https://abd-1234.azuredatabricks.net"
  token = "sdflkjsdf"
  alias = "dev-dbx-provider"
}


resource "databricks_cluster" "dev_cluster" {
  cluster_name = "xyz"
  spark_version = "10.4.x-scala2.12"
}
```

I am able to successfully import databricks_cluster.dev_cluster. Once imported, I update my config to output a value from the cluster in state. The updated config looks like this:

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.25.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.4.0"
    }
  }

}


provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "uat-sub"
  features {}  
  subscription_id = "sfsdf"
}

provider "databricks" {
  host  = "https://abd-1234.azuredatabricks.net"
  token = "sdflkjsdf"
  alias = "dev-dbx-provider"
}


resource "databricks_cluster" "dev_cluster" {
  cluster_name = "xyz"
  spark_version = "10.4.x-scala2.12"
}

output "atm"{
   value = databricks_cluster.dev_cluster.autotermination_minutes
}
```

When I run terraform apply on the updated config, terrform proceeds to refresh my imported cluster and detects changes and does an 'update-in-place' where some of the values on my cluster are set null (autoscale/pyspark_env etc). All this happens when no changes are actually being made on the cluster. Why is this happening? Why is terraform resetting some values when no changes have been made?

EDIT- 'terraform plan' output:

```
C:\Users\>terraform plan
databricks_cluster.dev_cluster: Refreshing state... [id=gyht]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # databricks_cluster.dev_cluster will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "databricks_cluster" "dev_cluster" {
      ~ autotermination_minutes      = 10 -> 60
      - data_security_mode           = "NONE" -> null
        id                           = "gyht"
      ~ spark_env_vars               = {
          - "PYSPARK_PYTHON" = "/databricks/python3/bin/python3" -> null
        }
        # (13 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - autoscale {
          - max_workers = 8 -> null
          - min_workers = 2 -> null
        }

      - cluster_log_conf {
          - dbfs {
              - destination = "dbfs:/cluster-logs" -> null
            }
        }

        # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

EDIT - Work around with hard coded tags:

```
resource "databricks_cluster" "dev_cluster" {
  cluster_name = "xyz"
  spark_version = "10.4.x-scala2.12"
  autotermination_minutes = 10
  data_security_mode = "NONE"
  autoscale {
    max_workers = 8
    min_workers = 2
   }
   cluster_log_conf {
      dbfs {
        destination = "dbfs:/cluster-logs"
      }
    }
    spark_env_vars = {
          PYSPARK_PYTHON = "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
    }
}
```

The workaround partially works as I no longer see terraform trying to reset the tags on every apply. But if I were to change any of the tags on the cluster, lets says I change max workers to 5, terraform will not update state to reflect 5 workers. TF will override 5 with the hard coded 8, which is an issue.

Comment: Can you show plan's output for the changes?

Comment: Which changes terraform is trying to update on the apply? `tags`?

Comment: @Marcin updated OP with plan and tag details.

Comment: @harshavmb, please see my edit for details.

Comment: `But if I were to change any of the tags on the cluster, lets says I change max workers to 5, terraform will not update state to reflect 5 workers. TF will override 5 with the hard coded 8, which is an issue.`


How terraform setting what you set in resource is an issue?

Comment: I don't see `autoscale` block being part of [databricks_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/cluster). Having done some dry run through the code, I see on `Update` function to detect [autoscale](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/v1.4.0/clusters/resource_cluster.go#L256) changes which isn't used during `Read` function. What's the value of `autoscale` block in state file? `8` & `2` respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first part of your question, Terraform has imported the actual values of your cluster into the state file but it cannot import those values into your config file (.hcl) for you so you need to specify them manually (as you have done).

By not setting the optional fields, you are effectively saying "set those fields to the default value" which in most cases is `null` (with the exception of the `autotermination_minutes` field which has a default of `60`), which is why Terraform detects a drift between your state and your config. (actual values from import vs. the default values of the unspecified fields).

For reference : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/cluster

For the second part of your question, you say

> lets says I change max workers to 5, terraform will not update state to reflect 5 workers.

if you mean you change the max workers from outside of Terraform, then Terraform is designed to override that field when you run `terraform apply`. When working with Terraform, if you want to make a change to your infrastructure, you always want to make the changes in your Terraform config and run `terraform apply` to make those changes for you.

So in your case if you wanted to change the max_workers to 5, you would set that value in the terraform config and run `terraform apply`. You would not do it from within Databricks. If that behaviour is problematic I would question whether you want to manage that resource with Terraform, as that is always how Terraform will work.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is regarding the max_worker tag changes, hope you have the var.tf file and if you had mentioned `var "max" {default=8}` in var.tf.

Then you can override this value explicitly by providing the required value while applying plan such as  `terraform plan -var="max=5"` and you can check in the plan output.
:)